# How to search a large database of IP addresses in a timely manner?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file being read like this:

```
with open(r"file.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    c = list(reader)
```

This operation produced 1 list of about 22000 other list. The format is:

```
[['10.0.0.0/24', 'random bla', 'vlan=22'], ['20.0.0.0/20', 'random bla 2', vlan=354] ...x22000]
```

This is an IP database containing only network, vlan, description, etc. I made a script to check the presence of an arbitrary input in the database. For each network that I need to check in the database, I need to do the following:

- Transform my string in an IPNetwork object (I am using the netaddr module).
- For each list in the CSV dump, transform the first element of the list inside the main list in an IP object with IPNetwork(CSV_inside_list[0]).
- If my string is in the CSV network, print the entire list (CSV_inside_list).
- Do this [number of IPs to compare] * [size of the database, currently 22K] = HUGE TIME consumption.

My request to you is: how can I speed this up? I cannot simply do "if my_ip in csv_database", because I need them to be IPNetwork objects, so e.g 10.0.0.1 matches if confronted with 10.0.0.0/24 because that IP is in the network range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're loading all networks into memory before checking the IPs, but you don't really need to do that, you can just iterate over your reader instead of converting it into a list.

Instead I would load all IP addresses to check into a list and sort them. Then it's possible to use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) to get all IPs from the list which are in a single network in logarithmic time, so instead of `O(m*n)` you'd have `O(m*log(n))`, plus the cost for sorting the list of addresses.

Should look similar to this*:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

def find_ips_in_network(network, sorted_ips):
    first = netaddr.IPAddress(network.first)
    last = netaddr.IPAddress(network.last)
    first_idx = bisect_left(sorted_ips, first)
    last_idx = bisect_right(sorted_ips, last)
    return sorted_ips[first_idx:last_idx]

sorted_ips = sorted(...)  # load ips as sorted list of netaddr.IPAddress
found_networks = dict()
# or collections.defaultdict(list) if you want all networks

with open(r"file.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        network = netaddr.IPNetwork(row[0])
        for ip in find_ips_in_network(network, sorted_ips):
            found_networks[ip] = row
            # or found_networks[ip].append(row) if using defaultdict

for ip in sorted_ips:
    if ip in found_networks:
        print ip, "found in:", found_networks[ip]
```

*Disclaimer: no guarantee for correctness

Edit: small optimization: since the index of the first address is calculated first, it can be used to restrict the lower bound when searching for the last index:

```
    last_idx = bisect_right(sorted_ips, last, first_index)
```

*Explanation:* `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to search a sorted list for a given value, and return the index at which the value would have to be inserted to mainain the sorting of the list. The difference between `bisect_left` and `bisect_right` is the case in which the value is already in the list (one or more times), `bisect_left` will return the index of the first match, `bisect_right` the index of the last + 1.
So in this case:

```
first_idx = bisect_left(sorted_ips, first)
```

Will return the index of the first IPAddress from `sorted_ips` which is bigger or equal than `first`, and

```
last_idx = bisect_right(sorted_ips, last, first_idx)
```

returns the index one after the last IPAddress smaller or equal than `last`.
We know that `first <= last`, so `fist_idx` must be `<= last_idx`, therfore the lower bound of the second search can be limited at `first_idx`.

That means the slice `sorted_ips[first_idx:last_idx]` contains all IPs from the list with `first <= ip <= last`. If no addresses in the list are equal or betweeen `first` and `last`, both indices will be the same, returning an empty list.

As binary search has a worst case performance of `O(log(n))`, this will be considerably faster to find which IPs from the list are in a network then checking all networks for all IPs, specially if the list of IPs to check is very large.

Comment: I'll try this and report if it's faster.  Thanks for answering

Comment: "return sorted_ips[first_idx:last_idx]" always returns the "sorted_IPs" list that I originally used to search in the database. Why is this? I am interested in the information in the database, not my own list. Can you help?

Comment: The function should return all ips in the list which are in the given network. As I understood it, you're trying for a list of IPs to find if they are in one of the networks from your csv, is that correct or did I misunderstand something? This solution would turn that around and check for all networks wich of the given IPs are in it.

Comment: I need to search for every IP I supplied a match in my CSV file. If a match is found, the function should return the list in which the network was found (so it should return something like ['10.0.0.0/24', 'Description', 'vlan=4324']) . Currently though it just returns the same IPs that I inserted as "search strings" and NOT the information found in the database :(

Comment: from the returned ips you could build a mapping of ip to row.. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow, this actually works and it's super fast!. I can't understand how does this work exactly. What does the value of first_idx and last_idx rappresent exactly? Why is this faster than my method? You are still going thorugh the 22K elements, and yet is considerable faster! If you can include these comments I will gladely give you the correct answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Added a more detailed explanation, I hope it's understandable. Also, I would suggest to change the title of this question, this isn't really about iterating but more about finding a large list of ip addresses in a large list of networks... That way sombody else having a similar problem may also find this question.